# mysql on wamp server,version 2.5

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have the wamp server,version 2.5 on my laptop.And I've been trying to work on it,but I always get an error stating
 "ERROR 1046 <3D000> : Aucene base n' a ete selectionnee" when i attempt to create a database
                                                                ...Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell MySQL which database to use e.g:

```
USE db_name;
```

Comment: i did..but yet the same problem